# Joda-Time compareTo NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, jodatime, drools

I'm using joda-time to keep track of several different types of dates (DateTime and DateMidnight) in a Drools file. As part of the when condition, I get the date of an object and then compare the dates of all other objects to make sure there's not a more recent object. The dates are in the same format (DateTime), but I consistently receive the following error when I try to send it a payload via Tomcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.DateTime.compareTo(Lorg/joda/time/DateTime;)
at edu.measure.growth.Rule_assume_first_measurement_is_valid586933554.defaultConsequence(Rule_assume_first_measurement_is_valid586933554.java:7)
at edu.measure.growth.Rule_assume_first_measurement_is_valid586933554DefaultConsequenceInvokerGenerated.evaluate(Unknown Source)
at edu.measure.growth.Rule_assume_first_measurement_is_valid586933554DefaultConsequenceInvoker.evaluate(Unknown Source)
```

This is the rule that it is referencing in the error log:

```
rule "assume first measurement is valid"
when
    // consider all measurements that have not been validated
    $m: Measurement($type: parameter, valid == false, $dt: date)
    // verify no measurements occur after target date
    not Measurement(parameter == $type, date<$dt))
then
    modify($m) {setValid(true);}
end
```

It seems to not want to compare using the < operator. Is this a common error others have gotten? I haven't been able to find anything about how to fix it, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For future reference, this was a bug that was fixed, but it reappeared in DROOLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What DROOLS version are you using?

It seems it was a bug that got fixed:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DROOLS-37?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel